# Get data from two tables using IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

**What i want to get?**

Get id,name,email of the people who have sent me friend_requests.
Two tables i have used on the basis of which i want to get the details

**signup** -> id,name,email,firmname and a few more columns.

**friends_requests** ->id,userId,sentRequests,receivedRequests,friends,dates

Please refer to the below two images.

**friends requests table**

[image]

**Signup table**

[image]

**What I am trying?**

```
SELECT * FROM signup WHERE signup.id IN 
(SELECT sentRequests FROM friends_request  WHERE friends_request.userId=46)
```

This query only gives one record, whereas if i use below query it gives 3 records

```
SELECT * FROM signup WHERE signup.id IN (47,48,49)
```

I know why second query is giving three records because of the IN clause and three id's

But this query will also give the same result which is 47,48,49

```
SELECT sentRequests FROM friends_request  WHERE friends_request.userId=46
```

**But why isn't the first query giving three records?**

When both the values are **same**? Then why isn't the result same?

Comment: can you please add the schema of the two tables here ?

Answer (score 1):

About table friends_requests. Column sentRequests violates [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).
if I am right, IN operator gets your information as full string, not as separate ID information.

```
SELECT * 
FROM signup 
WHERE signup.id IN ('47,48,49')
```

```
what is operator thinks IN ('47,48,49')
what You think IN (47,48,49)
```

You have to split column value '47,48,49' into returning rows so operator could understand, if you want to use IN operator...

Answer (score 0):

For it to work like you coded it,

```
SELECT sentRequests FROM friends_request  WHERE friends_request.userId=46
```

would have to give 3 rows with 47,48,49.
Because sentRequests  is a string it gives  one row with 47,48,49

If you want the 3 values go with:

```
select * from #signup a where exists (select 1 from friends_request b where  ','+sentRequests+',' like ',%'+cast(id as varchar(5))+',%')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT * FROM signup WHERE id IN (
SELECT 
    DISTINCT cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sentRequests, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) AS signed) sentRequests
FROM friends_request INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        0 digit 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT 4 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT 5 
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT 6
   ) n ON LENGTH(REPLACE(sentRequests, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(sentRequests)-n.digit
        WHERE userId = 46
);
```